# Weird output for git log --merges when merging feature branches

Tags: git, merge, git-log

I have the following Git repository tree:

```
C
|\
| B
|/
A 

A: No parents. Initial commit.
   Contains foo with content "ABC".
B: Parents: A. "Commit on feature branch".
   Contains foo with content "XYZ".
C: Parents: A, B. "Merge of feature branch".
   Contains foo with content "XYZ".
```

I expected `git log --merges foo` to show me commit `C`, however, the log is empty! Only if I specify `--first-parent` as well, it shows the merge commit `C`. Why is that so? Is this a bug in Git's default history simplification?

Unfortunately, the history simplification example in the Git docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) does not contain the very same situation as here (although it is probably the most common situation...).

Does anybody know, what happens? I'm pretty sure it has to do with Git's default history simplifcation algorithm, because if I specify `--full-history` the merge commit `C` is shown as well.

Does the default follow only the *second* parent in a commit for some reason?

Comment: How did you merge? `--no-ff`?

Comment: Yep. (to my understanding fast-forward merging would rebase B on A and would not even result in 3 commits, am I wrong?)

Comment: This seems like a bug: git is deciding to suppress commits that don't modify the tree in any interesting way, and your merge doesn't modify the tree "interestingly", so it suppresses commit `C` figuring it will show you some earlier commit.  But `--merges` means it skips `B` and `A` and then it runs out of commits and shows nothing.  Since `C` is a candidate, it probably should have put `C` aside as a commit-to-possibly-show (which must be cleared or replaced as it goes further back in history, and either shows some commit, or finds an older "possible").  But I'm not 100% sure of this.

Comment: To my understanding the default history simplification algorithm should show me commits where there is a diff to any parent and C has a diff to A, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the same question on the Git mailing list and got an appropriate answer:

Asking the log for a single file indeed turns on history simplification. Since the commit C completely used B, the changeset to A is pruned from the log output. Comparison to B is TREESAME, and is therefore pruned as well -> no output.

See http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/281256 for more information.